# Does the preprocessing of one algorithm change the conditions of the experiment?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, comparison, theory

As an example,

We have two algorithms that utilize the same dataset and the same train and test data:

1 - uses k-NN and returns the accuracy;

2 -applies preprocessing before k-NN and adds a few more things, before returning the accuracy.

Although the preprocessing "is a part of" algorithm number 2, I've been told that we cannot compare these two methods because the experiment's conditions have changed as a result of the preprocessing.
Given that the preprocessing is only exclusive to algorithm no. 2, I believe that the circumstances have not been altered.

Which statement is the correct one?

Comment: if they both use accuracy you can compare them. Accuracy is  a percentage, so you can compare both numbers and see which one has better accuracy. Note that accuracy is just one metric, which doesn't mean higher accuracy means better. Depending on your problem you might want to maximize another metric, like F-score.

Comment: It's a bit like having two runners that will run 100m. You give sport shoes to one and the other runs barefoot. You can of course compare the times they take to run 100m and see which one runs in a lower time. Whether the comparison is fair or not is debatable. Maybe runner1 (algorithm one) doesn't need preprocessing (shoes) because it runs better barefoot. So you need to define what compare means. You can always compare metrics if they have the same units. What you can do is for the same algorithm run it with or without preprocessing and see how it performs better.

Comment: If the preprocessing is considered part of algorithm 2, AND IT DOES NOT INVOLVE ANY ADDITIONAL INPUT, then of course you can compare them.  If you provide any other input, even input like deciding whether to run the preprocessing or not, or what kind, etc., then it's not a valid comparison.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you are comparing.

- if you compare the two methods "with preprocessing allowed", then you don't include the preprocessing in the experiment; and in principle you should test several (identical) queries;
- if you compare "with no preprocessing allowed", then include everything in the measurement.